# Load local Json file in Kotlin Multiplatform Library

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working in a Kotlin Multiplatform Library to share some logic for my native Android and iOS applications. I need to load a json file inside the commonMain directory, but I didn't find any documentation about that. I read about mocko-resources, but this dependency doesn't work for multiplatform libraries. I think this project is a multiplatform app project.

**Project structure**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFwu7.png

**iOS Code**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjogo.png

**Android Code**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzXgw.png

My idea is to open the local JSON and map the data into a Kotlin object. This is my project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement file operations separately on each platform.

The most straightforward way is to use [`expect` and `actual` declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-expect-actual.html).

With this, you write an 'interface' for your function in `commonMain`

```
// commonMain/GetJson.kt

expect fun getJsonFromFile(file: String): String
```

Then add implementations for each platform:

```
// androidMain/GetJsonAndroid.kt

actual fun getJsonFromFile(file: String): String {
    // Write code to read file using Android API
}

// iosMain/GetJsonIos.kt

actual fun getJsonFromFile(file: String): String {
    // Write code to read file using iOS API
}
```

You can then call your function from `commonMain` and complete your object creation using shared code.

```
// commonMain

class TargetObject(json: String) {
    // implement in common code
}

val targetObject = TargetObject(getJsonFromFile())
```

Comment: I have the implementation for each platform. But i see in the XCFramework, for example, i don't have a bundle with the json how is in the resources folder inside common in Kotlin project.

I don't know if I need to add any code to compile Android and iOS library with resources inside CommonMain.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Resources are not part of the common compilation. Deal with any resources separately in each target using the API for that platform, however you plan to access files stored on each device.

Comment: If you want to deserialize the json, I would use Kotlin serialization library. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization

Comment: I updated my question with three images (project structure, iOS, and Android implementation). I basically need to load a resource from a common folder to use the data inside an Android or iOS application. For example: 

Json inside commonMain with books: json [{ "name": "Book name" , "author" : "Author name}, { "name": "Book name" , "author" : "Author name}]  I need to parse this data in the Kotlin library to use in an Android or iOS application like this: MyKotlinLibraryCoreData.books to retrieve a list of books.

Comment: There are no common resources, no common folders and no common file system. Common is just a useful way of sharing Kotlin code and only Kotlin code. There are only two computer programs that can run, an Android one and an iOS one. If you want to use resources, you will have to figure out an Android way and an iOS way.